# How to increament global variable by 1 using foreach in xslt1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am processing an XML file where I want to keep count of number of nodes according to condition. If condition is true then increase the global variable by 1 and if false then doesn't increase. How to do this by using for-each loop.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

"Variables" in xslt aren't actually variable, they are immutable. Once you set them they are set, you can't increment them.

There are a number of other options detailed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833118/in-xslt-how-do-i-increment-a-global-variable-from-a-different-scope).