# XSLT: Getting the unique long number

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Is it possible to get a unique long number in xslt?
I am accessing more than one time in a single translation.
 I tried using using currentTimeStamp but it didn't work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:timeStamp="java.lang.System">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="Client">
            <xsl:variable name="ClientPK1" select="concat('-',timeStamp:currentTimeMillis())"/>
            <xsl:variable name="ClientPK2" select="concat('-',timeStamp:currentTimeMillis())"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to achieve with this approach, so that we can see whether or not we need to answer your question, or suggest a better solution for the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: I am sending xml request to legacy system. When Legacy system sees a PK with negative value, It inserts it in the table. That's why I have to send unique negative PKs.

Comment: What about having a variable with an initial value of -1, and decrementing it in each iteration?

Comment: Trying to keep it cleaner and curious if there is anyway to get unique long number.

Comment: I would have to agree with @ppeterka66's: create an `xsl:variable` and set it to -1, then decrement it with each PK selection so that it's always unique, which staying negative. Using a tracking variable is pretty clean, because it lets you document what the value is actually for; and well documented XSLT is the only truly useful XSLT

Comment: ok. How would I do it? Sorry I am new to XSLT.

Comment: If you're new to XSLT, an in/decrement counter can actually be really confusion since you can't "update" a variable -- you set it once, then perform your selection matching recursively with each recursive call in/decrementing the value as a parameter. There is a good SO post on how to achieve a 'global variable' similar to what you need, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833118/in-xslt-how-do-i-increment-a-global-variable-from-a-different-scope will be worth reading for you.

Answer (score 0):

Generating numbers is not part of the language (XSLT is functional). But still there are extensions you could use. Check out: [exslt.org](http://www.exslt.org)