# XSLT 2.0 - Converting array of elements to list

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Learning XSLT, and I would like to know if this transformation is possible

Input something like this

```
<book>
  <title>Title 1</title>
  <author>Author 1</author>
</book>
<book>
  <title>Title 2</title>
  <author>Author 2</author>
</book>
<book>
  <title>Title 3</title>
  <author>Author 3</author>
</book>
```

Output

```
<book1>
  <title1>Title 1</title1>
  <author1>Author 1</author1>
</book1>
<book2>
  <title2>Title 2</title2>
  <author2>Author 2</author2>
</book2>
<book3>
  <title3>Title 3</title3>
  <author3>Author 3</author3>
</book3>
```

What would the XSLT for this look like?

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833118/in-xslt-how-do-i-increment-a-global-variable-from-a-different-scope

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the `<xsl:element>` instruction that allows you to create an element with a calculated name, and at the position() function?

Comment: It's possible but it's probably a bad idea - if you have elements that represent the same kind of data then they should have the same name, you're just making more work for the downstream consumers of the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no idea why you would want to create such a horrible XML document, but if you must, you can do it using:

```
<xsl:template match="book">
  <xsl:variable name="n" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:element name="book{$n}">
    <xsl:element name="title{$n}">
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="author{$n}">
      <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments this is quite easy, but ill advised. However, if you acknowledge that it is ill-advised, then there is no reason to show how.

Firstly, in XSLT there are two ways to create an element, by placing the [element inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element):

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    <book1>
        <!-- Some stuff -->
    </book1>
<xsl:template>
```

Or programatically using the [`xsl:element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement) directive:

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:element name="book1">
        <!-- Some stuff -->
    </xsl:element>
<xsl:template>
```

The `@name` attribute in the above code can take an XPath expression if we use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template). Which means we can insert a dynamic value in there:

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:element name="book{//some/xpath/here()}">
        <!-- Some stuff -->
    </xsl:element>
<xsl:template>
```

Additionally, we can get the position of the current node *based on the current context* using the [position()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-position) Xpath function:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//book">
        <!-- this loop will number the books in the whole document 
             because its seaching in all nodes (//). -->
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="library">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//book">
        <!-- this loop will number the books in the current *library*
             because its seaching in all nodes under the library node (.//)  -->
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:template>
```

As Michael Kay showed in his answer as I was typing this (*grrr*), combining these is trivial.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense.